# how to return the tester to the beginning to ask user to input euro/gbp/cad

Tags: java, loops

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class CurrencyTester
{ 
public static void main(String[]args)
{
```

i want to loop from the beginning, but not to ask the user to type in for same converter, how do i do it?

```
    CurrencyConverter one= new CurrencyConverter();
    System.out.println("Convert dollar to euro/gbp/cad");
```

i want to ask for the input euro gbp or cad after the first loop

```
    System.out.println("enter euro/gbp/cad");
    System.out.println("");
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    String a = input.next();
    if("euro".equalsIgnoreCase(a))
    {
```

euro

```
do { 

System.out.println("Enter Dollars:");
Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
String d = in.next();
if ("Q".equalsIgnoreCase(d)) {
    System.out.println("Stop!");
    break;
} else {
try {
        double ds = Double.parseDouble(d);
        one.setDollar(ds);
        System.out.println("Euro:");
        System.out.println("€"+one.getCurrencyE());
    } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
        System.out.println("Not double,wrong input");
    }
}
} while (true);

}
    if("gbp".equalsIgnoreCase(a))
    {
```

GDP

```
do { System.out.println("Enter Dollars:");
Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
String d = in.next();
if ("Q".equalsIgnoreCase(d)) {
    System.out.println("Stop!");
    break;
} else {
    try {
        double ds = Double.parseDouble(d);
        one.setDollar(ds);
        System.out.println("GDP:");
        System.out.println("£"+one.getCurrencyG());
 } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
        System.out.println("Not double,wrong input");
 }
}
 } while (true);

}
    if("cad".equalsIgnoreCase(a))
    {
```

CAd

```
 do { System.out.println("Enter Dollars:");
Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
String d = in.next();
if ("Q".equalsIgnoreCase(d)) {
    System.out.println("Stop!");
    break;
} else {
try {
        double ds = Double.parseDouble(d);
        one.setDollar(ds);
        System.out.println("Canadian Dollar:");
        System.out.println("$"+one.getCurrencyC());
    } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
        System.out.println("Not double,wrong input");
    }
}
 } while (true);

 }
}
   }
  }
```

I tried to use while loop in the beginning ,but it doesn't work.

Comment: A little formatting would help with readability, e.g. correct intendation and a contiguous code block.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main problem with your existing code is that you have [duplicated](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duplicate_code) the same logic in three different places. What you instead want to do is group any code that is common for all your different cases into methods or otherwise structuring your logic so you don't have to duplicate it.

Here is one way to structure your code in a more readable and maintainable way:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    CurrencyConverter one = new CurrencyConverter();

    do{
        System.out.println("Convert dollar to euro/gbp/cad");

        System.out.println("enter euro/gbp/cad");
        System.out.println("");
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        String a = input.next();

        String d = enterDollars();

        if( d == null )
            break;

        try {
            double ds = Double.parseDouble(d);
            one.setDollar(ds);

            if( "euro".equalsIgnoreCase(a) )
                System.out.println("Euro:\n€" + one.getCurrencyE());
            else if( "gbp".equalsIgnoreCase(a) )
                System.out.println("GBP:\n£" + one.getCurrencyG());
            else if( "cad".equalsIgnoreCase(a) )
                System.out.println("Canadian Dollar:\n$" + one.getCurrencyC());
        }
        catch (NumberFormatException e) {
            System.out.println("Not double,wrong input");
        }

    } while (true);

}


private static String enterDollars(){
    System.out.println("Enter Dollars:");
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    String d = in.next();

    if ("Q".equalsIgnoreCase(d)) {
        System.out.println("Stop!");
        return null;
    } 

    return d;
}
```

I have put the code for getting user input in dollars into its own separate method, which makes the code easier to read. Similarly, you could further divide your code into smaller methods (like `enterCurrency()`, `presentResult()`, etc) to make your main method more readable.

Answer (score 0):

You are copying and pasting similar pieces of logic. This is not good practice and typically means you should start creating functions for similar behavior. I am not sure how far into programming you are so I am going to show you a simple way to get input from the user using a single do/while and another do while for grabbing a valid dollar amount.

Put this in your main

```
    CurrencyConverter one= new CurrencyConverter();
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Convert dollar to euro/gbp/cad");
    HashSet<String> conversions = new HashSet<>();
    conversions.add("euro"); 
    conversions.add("gdp"); 
    conversions.add("cad");

    System.out.println("");
    String userInput = "";
    do {
        System.out.println("enter euro/gbp/cad");
        userInput = input.nextLine();
        double amount = 0;
        //check to see if we need to get a dollar amount
        if(conversions.contains(userInput))
        {
            do {
                System.out.println("Enter Dollars:");
                String sAmount = input.nextLine();
                amount = Double.MAX_VALUE;
                //check it's a number before parsing
                if(sAmount.matches("\\d+"))
                {
                    amount = Double.parseDouble(sAmount);
                    //then set it for the object once
                    one.setDollar(amount);
                }
                else
                {
                    System.out.println("Error when parsing dollar amount: " + sAmount);
                    System.out.println("Please Try again!");
                }

            } while (amount != Double.MAX_VALUE);
        }
        //check for euro
        if(userInput.equals("euro"))
        {
            System.out.println("Euro: ");
            System.out.println("€"+one.getCurrencyE());
        }
        else if(userInput.equals("gdp"))
        {
            System.out.println("GDP: ");
            System.out.println("£"+one.getCurrencyG());
        }
        else if(userInput.equals("cad"))
        {
            System.out.println("Canadian Dollar: ");
            System.out.println("$"+one.getCurrencyC());
        }
        else if (!userInput.equals("quit"))
        {
            System.out.println("Error with input : " + userInput);
        }
    } while (!userInput.equals("quit"));
```